# JQuery Scroll with extracted function

Tags: jquery

can someone explain why my code do not work? I am just trying to extract a function:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('section.bgParallax').each(function(){
        var $obj = $(this);
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var yPos = -($(window).scrollTop() / $obj.data('speed')); 
            var bgpos = '50% '+ yPos + 'px'; 
           $obj.css('background-position', bgpos );
        }); 

});
```

and this do not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var doScroll = function($div) {
            var yPos = -($(window).scrollTop() / $div.data('speed')); 
            var bgpos = '50% '+ yPos + 'px'; 
           $div.css('background-position', bgpos );
        };

   $('section.bgParallax').each(function(){
        var $obj = $(this);
        $(window).scroll(doScroll($obj)); 

   });
});
```

I just tried to extract the function, but my function are not being called at scroll.

Comment: You can use ``console.log("something");`` to debug your code. Add ``console.log($obj);`` after ``var $obj = $(this);`` and ``console.log(yPos);`` after the first line within ``doScroll`` function.

Comment: i was debugging with console.log, and the functions are only being called on page load, not on scroll.

Comment: Any other idea? @coderz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `$(window).scroll` must be an event that receives a function as argument.

It doesn't work because you are calling your function `doScroll` and passing its return value as argument to `$(window).scroll`. You should pass your doScroll function instead:

`$(window).scroll(doScroll);`

But since you need to pass an argument to it you can wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    doScroll($obj);
});
```